# Make a child class inherit specific attributes from two different parent classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a problem with a Diamond inheritance exercise.

I have one base class A. Here is its constructor :

```
A::A(std::string name) : _hp(10), _ep(10), _ad(0)
{
    std::cout << "A object created !" << std::endl;
    return ;
}
```

Then, I have two parent classes B and C. Here are their constructors:

```
B::B(std::string name) : A(name)
{

    std::cout << "B object created !" << std::endl;
    this->_hp = 100;
    this->_ep = 50;
    this->_ad = 20;
    return;
}

C::C(std::string name) : A(name)
{
    std::cout << "C object created !" << std::endl;
    this->_hp = 100;
    this->_ep = 100;
    this->_ad = 30;
    return ;
}
```

And finally, I have one child class . Here is its constructor:

```
D::D(std::string name) : A(name + "_comes_from_A")
{
    this->_name = name;
    std::cout << "D object created !" << std::endl;
    this->_hp = C::_hp;
    this->_ep = B::_ep;
    this->_ad = C::_ad;
    return;
}
```

The D class inherits from class B and C.
The B and C classes both inherits from class A. I did something like this :

```
class A
{
    // code here

    protected:

    std::string _name;
    int         _hp;
    int         _ep;
    int         _ad;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
    // code here
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    // code here
};

class D : public B, public C
{
    // code here
};
```

As it can be noticed in the constructor of D class, I want it to inherits _ep from the B class (50) and _hp and _ad from the C class (100 and 30).

However, if I check the value of the _ep value in my D class, (with something like this for instance) :

```
std::cout << "ENERGY POINTS " << this->_ep << std::endl;
```

it is always equal to 100 (which comes from the C class).

I have noticed it depends on the order in which I handle inheritance for D class but I would like to be able to access values of any of the parent class from my child class. Can someone help me with that ? Thanks in advance!

MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE :

```
class A
{
    public :

    A(){
        return ;
    };
    A(std::string name) : _hp(10), _ep(10), _ad(0){
        std::cout << "A object created !" << std::endl;
        return ;
    };
    ~A(){
        std::cout << "A object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
        return ;
    };

    protected:

    std::string _name;
    int         _hp;
    int         _ep;
    int         _ad;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
    public :

    B(){
        return ;
    };
    B(std::string name) : A(name){
        std::cout << "B object created !" << std::endl;
        this->_hp = 100;
        this->_ep = 50;
        this->_ad = 20;
        return ;
    };
    ~B(){
        std::cout << "B object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
        return ;
    };
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    public :

    C(){
        return ;
    };
    C(std::string name) : A(name){
        std::cout << "C object created !" << std::endl;
        this->_hp = 100;
        this->_ep = 100;
        this->_ad = 30;
        return ;
    };
    ~C(){
         std::cout << "C object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
    return ;
    };
};

class D : public B, public C
{
    public :

    D(){
        return ;
    };
    D(std::string name) : A(name + "_comes_from_a"){
        this->_name = name;
        std::cout << "D object created !" << std::endl;
        this->_hp = C::_hp;
        this->_ep = B::_ep;
        this->_ad = C::_ad;
        std::cout << "HIT POINTS " << this->_hp << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ENERGY POINTS " << this->_ep << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ATTACK DAMAGE " << this->_ad << std::endl;
        return;
     }
     ~D(){
        std::cout << "D object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
        return ;
     };
};

int main(void)
{
     D  obj_D("TEST");
     return (0);
}
```

Comment: `this->_energy_points` ? There is no member of that name in your code

Comment: Sorry I edited my original code for simplicity, it is _ep ! I have corrected the typo

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, l am preparing it :)

Comment: btw there seems to be some confusion of virtual inheritance. "I would like to be able to access values of any of the parent class from my child class" virtual inheritance is somewhat the opposite of that. `D` has a single `A` parent

Comment: With the line  `class D : public B, public C` , I thought D would inherits both from B and C. But as B and C **virtually** inherits from A, D will have only a single A subobject.
Is it wrong ??

Comment: no its correct, but all members are members of `A`, hence they are present once

Comment: I have posted the code of the minimal reproducible example if you want to have a look. 
The output I get is :
`A object created !
D object created !
HIT POINTS 10
ENERGY POINTS 10
ATTACK DAMAGE 0
D object TEST destroyed.
C object TEST destroyed.
B object TEST destroyed.
A object TEST destroyed.`

But I would like to have : 
`A object created !
D object created !
HIT POINTS 100
ENERGY POINTS 50
ATTACK DAMAGE 30
D object TEST destroyed.
C object TEST destroyed.
B object TEST destroyed.
A object TEST destroyed.`

Comment: expected and actual output is part of a mre, you should include it in the question

Comment: I did it in the question

Comment: @Mitsun0bu your MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE is wrong. for B and C, you are calling the default constructor in D constructor. so _hp, _ep, _ad get their value from A constructor. the value is: HIT POINTS 10
ENERGY POINTS 10
ATTACK DAMAGE 0

Comment: Thank you @nader ! I knew it was wrong but I didn't know what to do exactly.
I tried this for my D constructor :   
`D(std::string name) : A(name + "_comes_from_a"), B(name), C(name)`

It gave me :   
HIT POINTS 100 ENERGY POINTS 100 ATTACK DAMAGE 30.  

I don't understand how to set energy points at 50 , as in B class ..

Comment: @Mitsun0bu the sequence of inheritance is matter. Change class D : public B, public C to  class D : public C, public B, and it will work.

Comment: @nader thanks , I tried that already but then I get : HIT POINTS 100 ENERGY POINTS 50 ATTACK DAMAGE 30. My D class inherits only from B class. What I would like to achieve is a combination of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got my program to work properly. Maybe I didn't explain well what I wanted to do, but I'm posting my solution here.
There are 4 classes A, B, C and D. They all have _hp, _ep and _ad variables.
D inherits from B **AND** C, which in turn inherit from A.
         A
        /     \
      B     C
       \      /
          D
I wanted my D class to take :

- _ep value from the B class
- _hp and _ad values from the C class

Here is the minimal reproducible example of the code that worked for me :

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

class A
{
    public :

        A(){
            return ;
        };

        A(std::string name) : _hp(10), _ep(10), _ad(0){
            std::cout << "A object created !" << std::endl;
            return ;
        };

        ~A(){
            std::cout << "A object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
            return ;
        };

    protected:

        std::string _name;
        int         _hp;
        int         _ep;
        int         _ad;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
    public :

        B(){
            return ;
        };

        B(std::string name) : A(name){
            std::cout << "B object created !" << std::endl;
            this->_hp = 100;
            this->_ep = 50;
            this->_ad = 20;
            return ;
        };

        ~B(){
            std::cout << "B object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
            return ;
        };

        static const int    EP = 50;
};

class C : virtual public A
{
    public :

        C(){
            return ;
        };

        C(std::string name) : A(name){
            std::cout << "C object created !" << std::endl;
            this->_hp = 100;
            this->_ep = 100;
            this->_ad = 30;
            return ;
        };

        ~C(){
            std::cout << "C object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
            return ;
        };

        static const int    HP = 100;
        static const int    AD = 30;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
    public :

        D(){
            return ;
        };
        D(std::string name) : A(name + "_comes_from_a"){
            this->_name = name;
            std::cout << "D object created !" << std::endl;
            this->_hp = C::HP;
            this->_ep = B::EP;
            this->_ad = C::AD;
            std::cout << "HIT POINTS " << this->_hp << std::endl;
            std::cout << "ENERGY POINTS " << this->_ep << std::endl;
            std::cout << "ATTACK DAMAGE " << this->_ad << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        ~D(){
            std::cout << "D object " << this->_name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
            return ;
        };
};

int main(void)
{
    D   obj_D("TEST");
    return (0);
}
```

The difference with the example that I posted in the question is that I declared `static const int` variables (**HP**, **EP** and **AD**) in my B and C classes. Thus, I am now able to access the values either from B or C classes in the constructor of class D. Typically, what I did earlier was wrong :

```
    // before (not working)
    this->_hp = C::_hp;
    this->_ep = B::_ep;
    this->_ad = C::_ad;   

    // now (working)
    this->_hp = C::HP;
    this->_ep = B::EP;
    this->_ad = C::AD;
```

The output is now :

```
A object created !
D object created !
HIT POINTS 100
ENERGY POINTS 50
ATTACK DAMAGE 30
D object TEST destroyed.
C object TEST destroyed.
B object TEST destroyed.
A object TEST destroyed.
```